# Unit testing Android and Permissions

Tags: android, unit-testing, permissions, android-testing

I need android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS for my Android application's junit tests. I am using IntelliJ Idea 11.1.2 and the unit tests in their own module, which contains second AndroidManifest.xml for the tests.

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />` to the test module's AndroidManifest.xml.

**Error:**`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider uri content://settings/system from pid=1063, uid=10035 requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS`

**Ugly quick fix:** I add the same permission also to the application's AndroidManifest.xml. Tests run without a single error.

**The problem:** I DO NOT want to give the whole application permission to change settings.

Is there a way to give permissions only for the tests?

Comment: Is the code that attempts to write the permissions in the test or in the application?

Comment: hey, did you get the workaround this problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Is there a way to give permissions only for the tests?

Short answer is no.

Your Android Test Project and Android Application Project are actually two applications, with test.apk instruments app.apk and run time. <uses-permission> is per application, added it to the test project's AndroidManifest.xml only gives required permission to test.apk, not the application under testing i.e. app.apk.

Comment: as you said, adding permission to the test project's AndroidManifest.xml only gives permission to the test.apk, I agree. then why the code written in the test getting this error when using this permission ?